# ¿Por qué en Odoo 8 no emite mensaje de aviso?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

- Plataforma: Odoo v8
- S.O: Ubuntu 14.04
- Lenguaje: Python 2.7

He creado una función que lee una fecha de un campo datetime, lo procesa para extraer sólo la fecha obviando la hora y luego me indica si es fin de semana o no, en caso de fin de semana tiene un condicional anidado que llama a un aviso del sistema. EL proceso no da error, pero luego no me deja mostrar el mensaje, aquí el código:

```
import datetime
# give advice it is impossible select weekends
@api.onchange("hora_llegada")
def stop_weekend(self):
    fecht = self.hora_llegada
    if fecht == False: # detect if field is empty
        pass
    elif fecht == True:
        day = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecht,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # converse to date
        conversion = datetime.datetime.strftime(day, "%Y-%m-%d") # converse to string and short to date
        weekno = datetime.datetime.strptime(conversion, "%Y-%m-%d").weekday() # converse to object and get week day
        if weekno > 5:
            warning = {'title': "Advertencia!",
                       'message': "No es posible seleccionar los fines de semana, gracias."}
            return {'warning': warning}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en castellano @marco-garcia-baturan. Si alguna de las respuestas responde a tus dudas recuerda marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desconozo como funciona odoo pero tal y como está escrito tu código nunca funcionará. Asumiendo que `self.hora_llegada` es una cadena de texto sucede que las dos comprobaciones que están haciendo son falsas

```
fecht == False # Devolverá falso
fecht == True # Devolverá falso
```

Si simplemente quieres comprobar que `fecht` no es un valor vacío debes o bien comprobar si es None con `fecht is None` o bien delegar en como python gestiona [los valores falsy](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/truth.html)

```
import datetime
# give advice it is impossible select weekends
@api.onchange("hora_llegada")
def stop_weekend(self):
    fecht = self.hora_llegada
    if fecht:
        day = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecht,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # converse to date
        conversion = datetime.datetime.strftime(day, "%Y-%m-%d") # converse to string and short to date
        weekno = datetime.datetime.strptime(conversion, "%Y-%m-%d").weekday() # converse to object and get week day
        if weekno > 5:
            warning = {'title': "Advertencia!",
                       'message': "No es posible seleccionar los fines de semana, gracias."}
            return {'warning': warning}
```

Ten en cuenta que la función sólo devolverá el valor de warning cuando fecht tenga algún valor y el número de semana sea > 5. Por otro lado una vez obtienes `day` no necesitas `conversion`, ya podrías hacer

```
weekno = day.weekday()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta Francisco. No sabía ése detalle de Python (y mira que me encanta éste lenguaje, pero es tan grande en potencialidad) voy a aplicar tu solución a ver que me dice Odoo.

Comment: AL final la parte crítica queda tal que así funcionando:

Comment: `fecht = self.hora_llegada
        if fecht is None: # detect if field is empty
            pass
        elif fecht:`